Microsoft Entra ID - User Concent Screen
I've been playing around with OAuth 2.0 using Microsoft Entra ID and wanted to find out why I'm seeing two consent screens.
Background:

I've created TWO app registrations:

One for a SPA frontend - call it: KATA Coffee SPA
One for Web API backend - call it: KATA Coffee Web API



For the backend App Registration:

I removed any default permissions that were added
I "Exposed an API/Created a scope"



For the frontend App Registration

I added the above scope as a permission (Main thing I'm testing)
Did the other required setups when setting up an app registration for a SPA.


Now the issue is that I see two consent screens. I was only expecting to see one. It is all working, but I'm not happy with the user seeing the second screen. I feel like it's not necessary and surly I'm doing something wrong.
The below is the first screen:

First we see the consent permission for the KATA Coffee Web API. This correct.
Second is the Microsoft Graph permission which is correct.

I'd expect to see the above as both permissions are being asked for in the frontend App Registration.

Now for the second screen which I'm not sure why I'm seeing.

First off, the user is consenting to the use of the KATA Coffee Web API on the first screen so no need to show this consent screen.
Secondly, the KATA Coffee Web API has no permission for anything so why is Microsoft Graph permission being asked?


Maybe I'm missing something or I'm not understanding how it's all linked up but I think it's a poor user experience to see a consent screen for a backend resource when they accepted it already.
Is what I'm seeing correct?

I created a KATA Coffee Web API app and exposed an API and added scopes and removed default permissions like below:

And in KATA Coffee SPA application, added API permissions like below:

Now when I tried to login by using sample endpoint, I got two consent screens as you:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://ClientID/access_as_user
&state=12345



Microsoft Entra ID considers the frontend and backend applications separately. Hence this can lead to two consent screens.

Hence as a workaround, you can configure client app that is KATA Coffee SPA as Authorized client applications in server app that is KATA Coffee Web API application:

Now the user is logged in without consenting twice:

Reference:
azure - The app is asking for consent twice in "app calls api" scenario - Stack Overflow by me

Hey @Rukmini, not sure why yours is working. I tried the above and it's still showing the second screen.
I feel like maybe it's a default scope/permission being forced on the Microsoft Entra ID end. As why is the second screen even showing graph permissions when that app registration has NO permissions?
I tried adding User.Read permission to KATA Coffee Web API and granting it admin consent to see if that would help but it did not.

Can you trying passing scope as mine and try?

My scope looked like this api://d7f8cc25-4318-ttttt-9891-tttttttt/access_as_user User.Read. When removing User.Read to match what you mentioned above. I now get no consent screen and redirected with code. This makes sense as I'm not asking for User.Read any more and the api://d7f8cc25-4318-ttttt-9891-tttttttt/access_as_user is trusted so no need to show a consent screen. This still doesn't help as I need a consent screen to the other permissions.

While adding scope you selected Admins and users can you set as Admin and try

Now requiring an admin login

Yeah here grant admin consent is required

Yes, I could grant admin consent to the access_as_user permission on the spa app registration but that would mean the user wouldn't need to consent to that permission which isn't what I'm after.

Got your requiremement but AFAIK by default Azure AD will display two consent screens in this scenario

And if you do not want consent screen at all then you need to configure authorized client application as suggested in answer

Can you try &prompt=consent in the request

no update. I'll leave this up to see if a solution comes along. Cheers.
